# How do I solve a syntax error in jupyter?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, jupyter

```
try: 
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO music_store2 (transaction_id, customer_name, cashier_name, year, albums_purchased) \
                 VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", \
                 (1, "Amanda", "Sam", 2000, ['Rubber Soul']))
except psycopg2.Error as e: 
    print("Error: Inserting Rows")
    print (e)



try: 
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO albums_sold (cashier_name, albums_purchased, year) \
                 VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", \
                 ("Sam", "My Generation", 2000))
except psycopg2.Error as e: 
    print("Error: Inserting Rows")
    print (e)
```

> File "", line 59
> except psycopg2.Error as e:
> ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I am trying to use the above insert statement as entries to create a table but I keep getting a syntax error in return. I have also included the query I used to create the table.

Comment: check ()[] in the previous line

Comment: Please edit your title to be specific. Imagine you are trying to find this 6 months from now. Hint: Jupyter is an IDE for running Python kernels or kernels of **many other languages** and so your error isn't "in jupyter".

Comment: I am going to say it is the `\`, mostly likely you have an empty space after it. The thing is it not necessary, remove it and see what happens. You would not need it even if you where continuing the string, just triple quote the string and empty space/ line returns, etc will be taken care of.

Comment: @hpaulj. This `['Rubber Soul']` is correct if the target field is an `array` type per [List adaption](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#adapt-list).

Comment: It should be: I am going to say it is the \.

Comment: Without loading `sql` I'm not going reproduce your error, but these `"....\ \nl ..." strings are suspect.  "\" as line continuation should not be within the quoted string.  If you want a multiline string use `"""one \nl two"""`

Comment: Welcome to SO. But you need to provide a [mre]. Your code do not reproduce the error. Are you using Python3?